# Excel Pivot Table Drill Down to Single Sheet (assistance with my current code)

Tags: vba, excel

Good day,

I have a report with a pivot table in Excel. My manager asked that when she double clicks in the pivot table, that the source data not be on a new sheet every time. Being a VBA noob, I managed to get assistance online, and I have the following code which does work, however I need some help tweaking it to get my desired result. Please could someone assist me.

Current workbook code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
If CS <> "" Then
With Application
ScreenUpdating = False
Dim NR&
With Sheets("DrillDown")
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(1)) = 0 Then
NR = 1
Else
NR = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 2
End If
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy .Cells(NR, 1)
End With
.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Delete
.DisplayAlerts = True
 Sheets(CS).Select
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target 
As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Movement Of Stock" Then
CS = "Movement Of Stock"
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "DrillDown" Then
If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
If Target.Row > Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1 _
Or Target.CurrentRegion.Cells(1, 1).Address = "$A$1" Then
Cancel = True
With Target.CurrentRegion
.Resize(.Rows.Count + 1).EntireRow.Delete
End With
End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Current module code:

```
Public CS$
```

The current code works fine, and drops the source data into the DrillDown worksheet, and then brings me back to my pivot table. When I double click somewhere else, again it works, and puts that data under the previous with a row separating.

1) What I would like is that every time I double click in the pivot table, any data in the DrillDown worksheet cleared first, and then new data added (in other words, I don't want the data to stack from each double click).

2) The current code also returns the user back to the pivot table after double clicking. I would like to the user to be taken to the DrillDown sheet rather.

Much appreciated for the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can meet your 2 requirements by just making changes to the NewSheet event.

I've commented the changes to make this self explanatory(?)

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
If CS <> "" Then
    With Application
        ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim NR&
        With Sheets("DrillDown")

            'Set this to always start at the top of the page
            NR = 1
            '..and to clear the Drilldown tab..
            .Cells.ClearContents

            'instead of this..
            '   If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(1)) = 0 Then
            '   NR = 1
            'Else
            '   NR = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 2
            'End If

            Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy .Cells(NR, 1)

        End With
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveSheet.Delete
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        'Below is commented out to stop user being returned to Pivot
        ' Sheets(CS).Select 
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works and I've learnt a few things. much appreciated